# ggplot line or bargraph between a range defined between two columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data frame where `V2` defines a start coordinate, `V3` defines the end coordinate and `V4` defines the coverage depth between `V2` and `V3`.

I want to plot a `barplot` in `ggplot2` where the bar height is defined as `V4` (on the y axis) and the bar width along the x axis is defined as the region that spans `V2` and `V3` with the entire x axis being the length of first row of `V2` (start of x axis) to row "z" of `V3` (end of x axis).

I cannot figure out how to plot a `bargraph` that is dependent of the two variables of the X axis (`V2` and `V3`). A line graph will work too.

[image: 1]

```
ff <- 
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "chr12", class = "factor"), 
    V2 = c(34443100L, 34443108L, 34443126L, 34443137L, 34443140L, 
    34443177L, 34443186L, 34443263L, 34443280L, 34443291L, 34443305L, 
    34443319L, 34443341L, 34443348L, 34443453L, 34443499L, 34443514L, 
    34443515L, 34443528L, 34443621L, 34443626L, 34443656L, 34443671L, 
    34443723L, 34443765L, 34443821L, 34443846L, 34443871L, 34443898L, 
    34443920L, 34443930L, 34443980L, 34444010L, 34444035L, 34444103L, 
    34444112L, 34444136L, 34444247L, 34444279L, 34444303L, 34444315L, 
    34444319L, 34444332L, 34444340L, 34444370L, 34444392L, 34444415L, 
    34444457L, 34444466L, 34444474L, 34444488L, 34444491L, 34444504L, 
    34444536L, 34444537L, 34444541L, 34444554L, 34444577L, 34444616L, 
    34444636L, 34444660L, 34444666L, 34444695L, 34444696L, 34444707L, 
    34444709L, 34444721L, 34444753L, 34444775L, 34444800L, 34444836L, 
    34444862L, 34444880L, 34444890L, 34444910L, 34444915L, 34444937L, 
    34444976L, 34445011L, 34445015L, 34445078L, 34445091L, 34445108L, 
    34445111L, 34445115L, 34445116L, 34445140L, 34445143L, 34445162L, 
    34445164L, 34445178L, 34445195L, 34445268L, 34445278L, 34445286L, 
    34445288L, 34445304L, 34445316L, 34445337L, 34445338L, 34445339L, 
    34445473L, 34445480L, 34445493L, 34445504L, 34445514L, 34445611L, 
    34445644L, 34445664L, 34445686L, 34445687L, 34445690L, 34445833L, 
    34445843L, 34445864L, 34445895L, 34445934L, 34446024L, 34446071L, 
    34446076L, 34446133L, 34446224L, 34446229L, 34446271L, 34446289L, 
    34446293L, 34446300L, 34446379L, 34446433L, 34446443L, 34446446L, 
    34446454L, 34446456L, 34446473L, 34446511L, 34446607L, 34446619L, 
    34446639L, 34446643L, 34446675L, 34446843L, 34446922L, 34446924L, 
    34446990L, 34447045L, 34447053L, 34447054L, 34447055L, 34447093L, 
    34447136L, 34447185L, 34447212L, 34447227L, 34447229L, 34447300L, 
    34447329L, 34447338L, 34447378L, 34447379L, 34447381L, 34447465L, 
    34447467L, 34447487L, 34447514L, 34447530L, 34447556L, 34447589L, 
    34447622L, 34447667L, 34447700L, 34447707L, 34447708L, 34447724L, 
    34447739L, 34447742L, 34447754L, 34447758L, 34447830L, 34447836L, 
    34447839L, 34447847L, 34447888L, 34447893L, 34447912L, 34447920L, 
    34447935L, 34447974L, 34447980L, 34448049L, 34448063L, 34448085L, 
    34448224L, 34448233L, 34448249L, 34448410L, 34448517L, 34448544L, 
    34448557L, 34448560L, 34448676L, 34448722L, 34448723L, 34448728L, 
    34448758L, 34448774L, 34448777L, 34448790L, 34448895L, 34448918L, 
    34448919L, 34448933L, 34448946L, 34448948L, 34448964L, 34448965L, 
    34448993L, 34449032L, 34449036L, 34449050L, 34449055L, 34449065L, 
    34449124L, 34449129L, 34449131L, 34449140L, 34449181L, 34449182L, 
    34449200L, 34449202L, 34449217L, 34449298L, 34449346L, 34449380L, 
    34449389L, 34449520L, 34449564L, 34449609L, 34449668L, 34449736L, 
    34449758L, 34449777L, 34449908L, 34449916L, 34450037L, 34450131L, 
    34450185L, 34450296L, 34450321L, 34450322L, 34450328L, 34450342L, 
    34450359L, 34450363L, 34450379L, 34450390L, 34450465L, 34450498L, 
    34450504L, 34450514L, 34450527L, 34450536L, 34450549L, 34450553L, 
    34450554L, 34450595L, 34450696L, 34450712L, 34450742L, 34450860L, 
    34450899L, 34450906L, 34450954L, 34451027L, 34451051L, 34451071L, 
    34451083L, 34451119L, 34451139L, 34451158L, 34451160L, 34451216L, 
    34451232L, 34451281L, 34451311L, 34451314L, 34451324L, 34451360L, 
    34451377L, 34451380L, 34451395L, 34451406L, 34451514L, 34451538L, 
    34451539L, 34451550L, 34451559L, 34451579L, 34451608L, 34451626L, 
    34451628L, 34451692L, 34451705L, 34451709L, 34451710L, 34451725L, 
    34451767L, 34451801L, 34451816L, 34451822L, 34451848L, 34451876L, 
    34451886L, 34451903L, 34451961L, 34451980L, 34451991L, 34452015L, 
    34452039L, 34452081L, 34452100L, 34452168L, 34452177L, 34452235L, 
    34452268L, 34452293L, 34452333L, 34452396L, 34452400L, 34452422L, 
    34452442L, 34452446L, 34452465L, 34452477L, 34452478L, 34452490L, 
    34452511L, 34452512L, 34452564L, 34452580L, 34452581L, 34452587L, 
    34452611L, 34452618L, 34452633L, 34452635L, 34452637L, 34452652L, 
    34452654L, 34452661L, 34452662L, 34452687L, 34452739L, 34452772L, 
    34452788L, 34452797L, 34452799L, 34452802L, 34452822L, 34452838L, 
    34452844L, 34452898L, 34452925L, 34452983L, 34452997L, 34453034L, 
    34453046L, 34453086L, 34453094L, 34453172L, 34453226L, 34453253L, 
    34453371L, 34453406L, 34453468L, 34453487L, 34453488L, 34453528L, 
    34453570L, 34453578L, 34453600L, 34453613L, 34453660L, 34453661L, 
    34453667L, 34453670L, 34453722L, 34453736L, 34453749L, 34453809L, 
    34453820L, 34443100L, 34443229L, 34443311L, 34443623L, 34443665L, 
    34443708L, 34443753L, 34444363L, 34444454L, 34444749L, 34444806L, 
    34446169L, 34446266L, 34446372L, 34446454L, 34446679L, 34446721L, 
    34446760L, 34446811L, 34447013L, 34447071L, 34447131L, 34447228L, 
    34448104L, 34448129L, 34448161L, 34448197L, 34448424L, 34448496L, 
    34448524L, 34448530L, 34448589L, 34448596L, 34449013L, 34449110L, 
    34450263L, 34450289L, 34450343L, 34450360L, 34450731L, 34450763L, 
    34451121L, 34451207L, 34451296L, 34451376L, 34451390L, 34451475L, 
    34451835L, 34451900L, 34452880L, 34452979L, 34452993L, 34453026L, 
    34453078L, 34453100L, 34453484L, 34453581L), V3 = c(34443108L, 
    34443126L, 34443137L, 34443140L, 34443177L, 34443186L, 34443263L, 
    34443280L, 34443291L, 34443305L, 34443319L, 34443341L, 34443348L, 
    34443453L, 34443499L, 34443514L, 34443515L, 34443528L, 34443621L, 
    34443626L, 34443656L, 34443671L, 34443723L, 34443765L, 34443821L, 
    34443846L, 34443871L, 34443898L, 34443920L, 34443930L, 34443980L, 
    34444010L, 34444035L, 34444103L, 34444112L, 34444136L, 34444247L, 
    34444279L, 34444303L, 34444315L, 34444319L, 34444332L, 34444340L, 
    34444370L, 34444392L, 34444415L, 34444457L, 34444466L, 34444474L, 
    34444488L, 34444491L, 34444504L, 34444536L, 34444537L, 34444541L, 
    34444554L, 34444577L, 34444616L, 34444636L, 34444660L, 34444666L, 
    34444695L, 34444696L, 34444707L, 34444709L, 34444721L, 34444753L, 
    34444775L, 34444800L, 34444836L, 34444862L, 34444880L, 34444890L, 
    34444910L, 34444915L, 34444937L, 34444976L, 34445011L, 34445015L, 
    34445078L, 34445091L, 34445108L, 34445111L, 34445115L, 34445116L, 
    34445140L, 34445143L, 34445162L, 34445164L, 34445178L, 34445195L, 
    34445268L, 34445278L, 34445286L, 34445288L, 34445304L, 34445316L, 
    34445337L, 34445338L, 34445339L, 34445473L, 34445480L, 34445493L, 
    34445504L, 34445514L, 34445611L, 34445644L, 34445664L, 34445686L, 
    34445687L, 34445690L, 34445833L, 34445843L, 34445864L, 34445895L, 
    34445934L, 34446024L, 34446071L, 34446076L, 34446133L, 34446224L, 
    34446229L, 34446271L, 34446289L, 34446293L, 34446300L, 34446379L, 
    34446433L, 34446443L, 34446446L, 34446454L, 34446456L, 34446473L, 
    34446511L, 34446607L, 34446619L, 34446639L, 34446643L, 34446675L, 
    34446843L, 34446922L, 34446924L, 34446990L, 34447045L, 34447053L, 
    34447054L, 34447055L, 34447093L, 34447136L, 34447185L, 34447212L, 
    34447227L, 34447229L, 34447300L, 34447329L, 34447338L, 34447378L, 
    34447379L, 34447381L, 34447465L, 34447467L, 34447487L, 34447514L, 
    34447530L, 34447556L, 34447589L, 34447622L, 34447667L, 34447700L, 
    34447707L, 34447708L, 34447724L, 34447739L, 34447742L, 34447754L, 
    34447758L, 34447830L, 34447836L, 34447839L, 34447847L, 34447888L, 
    34447893L, 34447912L, 34447920L, 34447935L, 34447974L, 34447980L, 
    34448049L, 34448063L, 34448085L, 34448224L, 34448233L, 34448249L, 
    34448410L, 34448517L, 34448544L, 34448557L, 34448560L, 34448676L, 
    34448722L, 34448723L, 34448728L, 34448758L, 34448774L, 34448777L, 
    34448790L, 34448895L, 34448918L, 34448919L, 34448933L, 34448946L, 
    34448948L, 34448964L, 34448965L, 34448993L, 34449032L, 34449036L, 
    34449050L, 34449055L, 34449065L, 34449124L, 34449129L, 34449131L, 
    34449140L, 34449181L, 34449182L, 34449200L, 34449202L, 34449217L, 
    34449298L, 34449346L, 34449380L, 34449389L, 34449520L, 34449564L, 
    34449609L, 34449668L, 34449736L, 34449758L, 34449777L, 34449908L, 
    34449916L, 34450037L, 34450131L, 34450185L, 34450296L, 34450321L, 
    34450322L, 34450328L, 34450342L, 34450359L, 34450363L, 34450379L, 
    34450390L, 34450465L, 34450498L, 34450504L, 34450514L, 34450527L, 
    34450536L, 34450549L, 34450553L, 34450554L, 34450595L, 34450696L, 
    34450712L, 34450742L, 34450860L, 34450899L, 34450906L, 34450954L, 
    34451027L, 34451051L, 34451071L, 34451083L, 34451119L, 34451139L, 
    34451158L, 34451160L, 34451216L, 34451232L, 34451281L, 34451311L, 
    34451314L, 34451324L, 34451360L, 34451377L, 34451380L, 34451395L, 
    34451406L, 34451514L, 34451538L, 34451539L, 34451550L, 34451559L, 
    34451579L, 34451608L, 34451626L, 34451628L, 34451692L, 34451705L, 
    34451709L, 34451710L, 34451725L, 34451767L, 34451801L, 34451816L, 
    34451822L, 34451848L, 34451876L, 34451886L, 34451903L, 34451961L, 
    34451980L, 34451991L, 34452015L, 34452039L, 34452081L, 34452100L, 
    34452168L, 34452177L, 34452235L, 34452268L, 34452293L, 34452333L, 
    34452396L, 34452400L, 34452422L, 34452442L, 34452446L, 34452465L, 
    34452477L, 34452478L, 34452490L, 34452511L, 34452512L, 34452564L, 
    34452580L, 34452581L, 34452587L, 34452611L, 34452618L, 34452633L, 
    34452635L, 34452637L, 34452652L, 34452654L, 34452661L, 34452662L, 
    34452687L, 34452739L, 34452772L, 34452788L, 34452797L, 34452799L, 
    34452802L, 34452822L, 34452838L, 34452844L, 34452898L, 34452925L, 
    34452983L, 34452997L, 34453034L, 34453046L, 34453086L, 34453094L, 
    34453172L, 34453226L, 34453253L, 34453371L, 34453406L, 34453468L, 
    34453487L, 34453488L, 34453528L, 34453570L, 34453578L, 34453600L, 
    34453613L, 34453660L, 34453661L, 34453667L, 34453670L, 34453722L, 
    34453736L, 34453749L, 34453809L, 34453820L, 133851895L, 34443229L, 
    34443311L, 34443623L, 34443665L, 34443708L, 34443753L, 34444363L, 
    34444454L, 34444749L, 34444806L, 34446169L, 34446266L, 34446372L, 
    34446454L, 34446679L, 34446721L, 34446760L, 34446811L, 34447013L, 
    34447071L, 34447131L, 34447228L, 34448104L, 34448129L, 34448161L, 
    34448197L, 34448424L, 34448496L, 34448524L, 34448530L, 34448589L, 
    34448596L, 34449013L, 34449110L, 34450263L, 34450289L, 34450343L, 
    34450360L, 34450731L, 34450763L, 34451121L, 34451207L, 34451296L, 
    34451376L, 34451390L, 34451475L, 34451835L, 34451900L, 34452880L, 
    34452979L, 34452993L, 34453026L, 34453078L, 34453100L, 34453484L, 
    34453581L, 133851895L), V4 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
    5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    7L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 
    5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
    5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), V5 = c("Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
    "Long", "Long", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", 
    "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", 
    "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", 
    "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", 
    "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", 
    "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", 
    "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", 
    "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Short", 
    "Short", "Short", "Short")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, -447L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to give de dataframe as an R object instead of an image? You can use the `dput` function to do so.

Comment: Thanks for including the `dput` output, but it's not loading for me. I wonder whether your data is complete, since when I try to load the data you provided, I only see 372 values for V2 and V3, but 447 for the others. (And that's after manually trying to load the vectors separately -- the object as provided doesn't load w/o error for me.)

Comment: In general, this sounds like it might be a good situation to use `geom_rect` since you have the min and max for X and Y for each shape you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what is requested but this is the barplot from height being the V4 value and the widths of the bars being the difference row-wise of V3 and V2.

```
barplot(height=ff$V4, width=ff$V3 -ff$V2)
```